# Can't retrieve data from Firebase database as admin

Tags: javascript, firebase

I can write to my `users` table using admin from my server, but I am unable to retrieve data.

When watching my console, I don't see any messages when running the following code.

I expect to see the email address associated with the looked-up selector output to the console.

```
// Get info from persistent login cookie
var cookie = req.cookies.rememberme.split(':')
var selector = cookie[0]
var token = cookie[1]

var db = firebaseAdmin.database()
var userRef = db.ref('users')
  .orderByChild('selector')
  .equalTo(selector)
  .once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
    console.log("Email: " +  dataSnapshot.val().email)
  })
```

I can confirm that the cookie exists and the `selector` variable is being set when the script is being run.

The entries in the `users` table are organized as follows:

```
key: {
  selector,
  token, 
  email
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the credentials for the service account.

I had originally chosen "Other > Firebase Rules System" (since none of the other options mention (Firebase), but it should be something from the "Project" section.

I created a new service account with the "Project > Owner" permission, uploaded the new certificate, and I can retrieve from the database as expected.

More information here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to set the read/write privileges in the rules tab on the database view on the firebase console?

Comment: Yes, both are set to false. As mentioned, I can write but not read.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't make a difference. I'm also now checking for errors and still no output in the console.